# Как сделать у не кликабельного блока hover

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Есть код который проверят есть ли в массиве строка '1', далее нужно было если есть, то сделать блок кликабельным, иначе не кликабельным. Если не кликабельный то вывести в блоке надпись. Делал через css свойство pointer-events. Тут все ок. Но нужно сделать так что бы эта надпись появлялась только при наведении на этот блок мыши. Наведении мыши не срабатывает так как "pointer-events", "none". Можно ли как то обыграть ситуацию? Или искать другой подход без использования pointer-events.

```
    if(prod_arr.indexOf('8888')!= -1){
        var cart_arr = [];
        $('.cart_prov1').each(function() {
            cart_arr.push($(this).text());
        });
        if(cart_arr.indexOf('1')!= -1){
            $("#product-skus li:nth-child(2)").css("pointer-events", "auto");
        }
        else{
            $("#product-skus li:nth-child(2)").css("pointer-events", "none");
            $("#product-skus li:nth-child(2)").css("background", "#826a91");
            $("#product-skus li:nth-child(2)").append('<p class="pri_akb">Что-бы получить товар по этой цене, Вам необходимо добавить в корзину товар 111</p>');
            console.log("fdwefrew2121")

        }
    }
```

Comment: как вариант: повесить класс на "выключенный" элемент и при наведении (через js/jq) проверять наличие этого класса и выводить соответствующее сообщение

Comment: В том то и дело наведения не срабатывают из за pointer-events

Comment: 'есть ли в массиве строка' - в массиве чего? блоков? опишите отношения между массивом и блоками.